# Pivot in sql server while using functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[performance] 
@startdate nvarchar(100), 
@enddate nvarchar(100) as begin declare @date1 nvarchar(100)=convert(varchar, @startdate+'00:00:00.000',120)  declare @date2 nvarchar(100)= convert(varchar, @enddate+'23:59:59.000',120)   set NOCOUNT on;
select l.LocName,v.Vtype,
 SUM(convert(numeric(18, 2), DATEDIFF(MI,t.DelDate,t.Paydate))) as TotalDiff,[dbo].[testfunctionstacknew](
   CONVERT(decimal(10,1), AVG( CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), DATEDIFF(SS,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) ) )))  as Average
from Transaction_tbl t left join VType_tbl v on t.vtid=v.vtid left join Location_tbl l on t.Locid=l.Locid 
where t.Locid in(select t1.Locid  from Transaction_tbl t1) and dtime between @date1 and @date2 and Status =5 group by v.Vtype,l.LocName,l.Locid order by l.Locid
end
```

I am getting out put like this:

```
LocName   Vtype    TotalDiff   Average
Address   Normal     15         00:10:01
Adress    vip        18         00:08:01
Address   VVIP        9         00:04:00
Address   Pass       20         00:15:00
Goldsouk  normal     45         00:18:08
Goldsouk   vip       17         00:11:36
Fashion    vip       78         00:35:25
Fashion    VVip      2          00:01:00
```

but i need output in different model as

```
LocName     Normal      Vip      VVip        Pass        Staff
Address     00:10:01    00:08:01  00:04:00    0           0
GoldSouck    00:18:08   00:11:36   0          0           0
Fashion      0          00:35:25   00:01:00   0           0
```

For getting out put like i know i have to use pivot..but i dont know how to use this? if any one know please help me to find out..i cant hardcord my vtype..actulay vtype is dynamic.that is coming from Vtype Table..if any one know how to resolve this issue..please help me to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pivot manually:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[performance]
(
    @startdate nvarchar(100), 
    @enddate nvarchar(100)
)
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare
        @date1 nvarchar(100)=convert(varchar, @startdate+'00:00:00.000',120)
        @date2 nvarchar(100)= convert(varchar, @enddate+'23:59:59.000',120)

    ;with cte as (
        select
            l.LocName, v.Vtype,
            sum(datediff(mi, t.DelDate, t.Paydate)) as TotalDiff,
            dbo.testfunctionstacknew(
                convert(decimal(10,1),
                    avg(convert(numeric(18,2), datediff(ss, t.Paydate, t.DelDate))
                )
            ) as Average
        from Transaction_tbl as t
            left join VType_tbl as v on t.vtid = v.vtid
            left join Location_tbl as l on t.Locid = l.Locid 
        where
            t.Locid in(select t1.Locid from Transaction_tbl as t1) and
            t.dtime between @date1 and @date2 and
            t.Status = 5
        group by v.Vtype, l.LocName, l.Locid
    )
    select
        c.LocName,
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'Normal' then Average end) as Normal,
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'Vip' then Average end) as Vip,
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'VVip' then Average end) as VVip,
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'Pass' then Average end) as Pass,
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'Staff' then Average end) as Staff
    from cte as c
    group by c.LocName
    order by c.LocName
end
```

Comment: while executing am getting error like this:Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.am passing date like this:2013-01-01 and 2013-08-01